# why elasticsearch keyword search not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

i use NLog to write log message to Elasticsearch, the index structure is here:

```
"mappings": {
    "logevent": {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "MachineName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "level": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get results using a text search:

```
GET /webapi-2022.07.28/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "ERROR" 
    }
  }
}
```

> result
> "hits" : [
> {
> "_index" : "webapi-2022.07.28",
> "_type" : "logevent",
> "_id" : "IFhYQoIBRhF4cR9wr-ja",
> "_score" : 4.931916,
> "_source" : {
> "@timestamp" : "2022-07-28T01:07:58.8822339Z",
> "level" : "Error",
> "message" : """2022-07-28 09:07:58.8822|ERROR|AppSrv.Filter.AccountAuthorizeAttribute|[KO17111808]-[172.10.2.200]-[ERROR]-"message"""",
> "MachineName" : "WIN-EPISTFOBD41"
> }
> }
> //.....
> ]

but when i use keyword, i get nothing:

```
GET /webapi-2022.07.28/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "message.keyword": "ERROR"
    }
  }
}
```

i tried term and match, the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

this is happening due to message field not just containing `ERROR` but also having other string in the `.keyword` field, you need to use the `text` search only in your case, you can use the `.keyword` field only in case of the exact search.

If your `message` field contained only the `ERROR` string than only searching on your `.keyword`  would produce result, you can test it yourself by indexing a sample document.

Comment: thx, I see what you mean. but i still have a question, if i have a text type string like `A.B.C` , how can i search such string which contains `B` ? i use `B` `B*`, but not work,it seems `A.B.C` is a word

Comment: @zhenghaoli, you need to use the wildcard field and query if you want to do wildcard search, its explained very nicely with datatype and type of queries in offical Elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type